# Experience Profile search - System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException errir

Tags: solr, content-search, experience-profile

In Sitecore 8.1-3 when we go to Experience Profile and do a simple search sometimes (not all the time) we get zero results when we know that there are entries in the index and we see a message that just says "An error has occurred". I have looked in all of the log files and I don't see any error messages anywhere.  Any ideas?  Below is a screen shot.

[image]

EDIT: adding more info.

We are using SOLR 4.10. I looked in the browser console and I do see an error. It says that there is a 500 Internal Server Error when I attempt this search. And the URL that it shows is this: `/sitecore/api/ao/v1/contacts/search?&pageNumber=1&sort=visitCount%20desc&match=don`.

I looked in Event Viewer and I can't seem to find any error that matches this. So I'm not sure why it is having issues.

UPDATE: The very strange thing here is that I only get this error for certain queries. As an example, if I search for "day" then I don't get any errors and the results return normally.  However if I search for "don" then I get an error.

UPDATE2: I was able to look in my browser console and find more information about the exception.  Here is the full exception information:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.\r\nParameter name: value",
  "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.DateTime.AddTicks(Int64 value)\r\n   at Sitecore.Cintel.Client.Transformers.TimeConverter.FormatDateTime(DateTime time, String format)\r\n   at Sitecore.Cintel.Client.Transformers.Contact.ContactSearchResultTransformer.ExtendResult(IContactSearchResult result, DateTime nowTime)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Sitecore.Cintel.Client.Transformers.Contact.ContactSearchResultTransformer.Transform(ResultSet`1 resultSet)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Comment: Please add some more details about the setup, most importantly if you're using Lucene or SOLR and also check if there's any errors in your console window of your browser or any failed requests in the network tab.

Comment: Added more info about the search engine and the browser console error

Comment: please check sitecore logs (sitecore and search log) for any errors

Comment: As I said in the original post I have looked in all of the Sitecore logs (sitecore and search) and can not find any errors.

Comment: @CoreyBurnett if you are seeing a 500 error, there has to be an exception on the server side. What happens when you paste the same url in the browser?

Comment: When I paste that URL in the browser it works fine.

Comment: Checking the code it's likely a result.LatestVisitStartDateTime that is invalid / corrupted? When you look into the index for your contacts do you see any fields like this or in your mongo that contain values that may cause this issue?

Comment: When I paste the URL in the browser I can see that lots and lots of the results have a LatestVisitStartDateTime that looks like this: 0001-01-01T00:00:00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Main Issue

This issue here is because of a negative offset in your Timezone. If you are based on a timezone that is negative offset to GMT (AKA all of the North and South Americas) then this is a bug that affects you.

To test this issue yourself, change your timezone to a POSITIVE offset (Like +4 HOURS GMT) and then rerun your Search in Experience Profile.

### Solution

The solution is found in Sitecore Support Public Reference Number 74085.

1. Put the attached Sitecore.Support.74085.dll assembly into the \bin folder.
2. Put the attached Sitecore.Support.74085.config file into the \App_Config\Include\ExperienceProfile folder.

The Sitecore Support Github page for this fix, including the download zip can be found here: https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.74085/releases

Alternatively, download the fix files directly here:

- [Sitecore.Support.74085.dll](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XGFatSH0t3VWpNeFFsaGktV00/view?usp=sharing%20)
- [Sitecore.Support.74085.config](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XGFatSH0t3bDRBTVltZE5nbFE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the fix!  I edited your answer to include a link to this fix (and downloads) on the Sitecore Support Gihub page.